# SQL Report - query multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

I have been working on a Stats page in APEX and currently have the following report query:

```
select to_char(DATELOGGED,'Month - YYYY') as Month, 
COUNT(*) as "Total Calls",
 SUM(case when CLOSED is null then 1 else null end) as "Open",
 COUNT(case CLOSED when 'Y' then 1 else null end) as "Closed",
 SUM(case when EXTREF is null then 0 else 1 end) as "Referred",
 round((COUNT(case SLA_MET when 'Y' then 1 else null end)/COUNT(case CLOSED when 'Y' then 1 else null end)*100),2) as "SLA Met %"

 from IT_SUPPORT_CALLS 
GROUP BY to_char(DATELOGGED,'Month - YYYY')
order by MIN (DATELOGGED) desc
```

I wish to add the sum of DURATION from a different table:

```
select
"START_TIME",
DECODE(DURATION,null,'Open',((select extract( minute from DURATION ) 
    + extract( hour from DURATION ) * 60
    + extract( day from DURATION ) * 60 * 24
  from dual)||' minutes')) DURATION
from "IT_DOWNTIME"
```

The IT_DOWNTIME table uses START_TIME (varchar2) as the date identifier, the IT_SUPPORT_CALLS uses DATELOGGED (DATE) as date identifier.

The current output for IT_DOWNTIME is for example:

08-FEB-2019 - 30 Minutes

20-FEB-2019 - 15 Minutes

I would like the report SUM and group IT_DOWNTIME and add this into the existing report.

Hope this makes sense.

Please let me know if I missed any information that would help to resolve this.

Many thanks

**Thanks for that, much appreciated.  Unfortunately it doesn't return any data from IT_DOWNTIME.**
I'm guessing the different date formats doesn't help, hope this clears things up a bit:

These are the columns in IT_DOWNTIME that are of interest:
START_TIME ( VARCHAR2(30) )
DURATION ( INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6) )

Example of current IT_DOWNTIME output without formatting:

> START_TIME
>
> > 06-JUL-2016 11:05
>
> DURATION
>
> > +00 00:35:00.000000

Example of current IT_SUPPORT_CALLS output without formatting:

> DATELOGGED
>
> > 06/07/2016

Comment: Please post some sample data and needed result to clarify your need (formatted text, please)

Comment: What data type is DURATION?

Comment: `IT_DOWNTIME table uses START_TIME (varchar2)` - this makes me sad. Oracle does have a DATE datatype.. :/

Comment: `The current output for IT_DOWNTIME is for example:` - the query you posted selects only one column and hence cannot produce the output you claim, please fix this up..

Comment: @Caius Jard
SQL is not our bread and butter, merely something we do on the side. The tables have never been refreshed since they were put in place in a rush over 15 years ago.

Comment: @Caius Jard,
Apologies, DURATION has  (INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)) as DATATYPE.
And yes, I'm very aware of the absolute mess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will probably do it, but there has been some guesswork as to your column names etc:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      to_char(DATELOGGED,'MON-YYYY') as Month, 
      COUNT(*) as Total_Calls,
      SUM(case when CLOSED is null then 1 else null end) as case_Open,
      COUNT(case CLOSED when 'Y' then 1 else null end) as case_Closed,
      SUM(case when EXTREF is null then 0 else 1 end) as case_Referred,
      round((COUNT(case SLA_MET when 'Y' then 1 else null end)/COUNT(case CLOSED when 'Y' then 1 else null end)*100),2) as percent_SLA_met
    FROM IT_SUPPORT_CALLS 
    GROUP BY to_char(DATELOGGED,'MON-YYYY')
  ) calls
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT  
      SUBSTR(START_TIME, 4) as down_month,
      SUM(extract(minute from DURATION) + 
        extract(hour from DURATION) * 60 +
        extract(day from DURATION) * 60 * 24
      ) || 'minutes' as total_down_mins 
    FROM IT_DOWNTIME 
    WHERE duration is not null
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(START_TIME, 4)
  ) downs
  ON calls.month = downs.down_month
```

Changed your date formatting of the first query to be MON-YYYY to make it align with what you claim is the formatting of the varchar2 date of the second query (dd-mon-yyy), and substringed the date to remove the day, leaving just the month

Edit:

Ok, so since you've posted some different example data from IT_DOWNTIME I see the problem: there's a time on the date also. Your first sample data didn't contain this time, it was just a date (as a string) so I was doing...

```
SUBSTR('01-JAN-1970', 4)
```

...to reduce the day date to a month date ('JAN-1970') and this was intended to align with the stuff going on in the other table ( to_date() with a format of 'non-yyyy' )

Now we know that there is a time in there too, of course it won't align because...

```
SUBSTR('01-JAN-1970 12:34', 4)
```

...produces 'JAN-1970 12:34' and this will then not match to anything from the other table (which will be just 'JAN-1970' without the time), so the left join means that nulls will be output

The solution is to change the SUBSTR call so it cuts 8 characters, starting at position 4:

```
SUBSTR(start_time, 4, 8)
```

This will remove the day and the time, leaving just the month-year that we need. You'll need to make the change in two places in the query above..

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately it doesn't return any data from IT_DOWNTIME.

Will expand on the IT_DOWNTIME table for it to make more sense, (currently editing text)

Comment: Based on the data that you say IT_DOWNTIME already contains it seems unlikely that the grouping query "doesn't return any data" - see this example here that uses the exact data you posted, returning 45 minutes (as you'd expect), link here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f980ba2bd30a5c229453aa32959da81d

Comment: I've edited my original post hoping to clear things up a bit

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the delay on replying to this.  However, that is working perfectly Caius, thanks very much!  So to be complete, had to change your above code to:

```
SUBSTR(START_TIME, 4, 8) as down_month,
```

and

```
GROUP BY SUBSTR(START_TIME, 4, 8)
```